# Run Bash Script on Booting mac

Tags: iphone, macos, applescript

i have a bash script **script.sh** in my desktop folder. When i am running it from terminal(cd desktop->bash script.sh), my server got started.

but i want to run this on launching mac.  i saw many places for that create a plist file in Library/LaunchAgent i create a plist file but it did't worked

anyone have idea whats wrong with me

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>com.example.loginscript</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
     <string>/bin/bash</string>
     <string>/Users/salonisajwan/Desktop</string>
     <string>bash script.sh</string>

    </array>
    <key>KeepAlive</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Comment: Best is to run it via `launchd`, but you can also put it in a subdirectory of `/Library/StartupItems`. See https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/macosx/conceptual/bpsystemstartup/chapters/StartupItems.html

Comment: @Barmar i add a plist file but it did't worked can you tell me what is  wrong with it...

Comment: What does this have to do with iphone or applescript? You should edit your labels.

Comment: @Barmar: Putting this in /Library/StartupItems will *not* work -- startup items have an entirely different format from launchd items.

Comment: @GordonDavisson The plist file wasn't in the question when I made my original comment, he just talked about the shell script.

Comment: @GordonDavisson can you tell me how is possible

Comment: @iSuman: Don't worry about StartupItems, they're a distraction. Follow Barmar's recommendations, and debug from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ProgramArguments` should be:

```
<key>ProgramArguments</key>
<array>
    <string>/bin/bash</string>
    <string>/Users/salonisajwan/Desktop/script.sh</string>
</array>
```

You should also change the `Label` to something more descriptive, not the label from the example.

Comment: thanks i modify my plist can you tell me how can i test it.(now i am restarting mac each time for testing this plist)

Comment: You can start it manually with `launchctl load /path/to/plistfile`.

Comment: I test using launchctl load this is telling me already loaded. after i hit launchctl list this shown me list of all runnng script(i think) my script also hereit mean my script is also running..???

Comment: Since it's loaded by default when you login, that's to be expected. You can use `launchctl unload` to unload it, modify the file, then load it again.

Comment: You can test with launchctl start /path/to/plistfile . Also, you can tail /var/log/system.log for problems.